# Removing special characters from file names bash script

Tags: bash

I have this bash script which I need to modify so it also includes "=" and ";".

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash


find . -depth -name "*[,&<>*?|\":'()]*" |     # Find all files or folders containing 'bad' characters.
while read FILEDIR                            # Read them line-by-line.
do
        DIR="${FILEDIR%/*}"                   # Get the folder its inside
        FILE="${FILEDIR/*\/}"                 # Get the plain name.
        NEWFILE="${FILE//[,&<>*?|\":\'()]/_}" # Substitute _ for bad things.
        mv "$DIR/$FILE" "$DIR/$NEWFILE"  # Rename it.
done
```

Comment: I execute to with ./script.sh ./FOLDER

Comment: you need to be a little bit more specific about your problem/what you are trying to do...

Comment: I'm using the bash script to remove special characters from file names recursively in a folder. So it will remove a ? question mark but I want it to remove a ; & =.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There is a high chance of getting duplicate filenames, you should (at least) use `mv -i`, or maybe check to see if the file already exists before overwriting it with an `mv`.

Comment: There can be so many other 'bad' characters (e.g., ASCII control characters). Consider a white list of acceptable characters.

Comment: The current approach isn't perfect (a filename containing a newline would break it, for example) but if you're happy with it, it's unclear why you don't just add the extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
NEWFILE=$(echo -n "$FILE" | tr -c '[:alnum:][:blank:]_-' _)
```

Unfortunately, it costs a fork with each file.